# awk and matching a literal backslash in a string

Tags: shell, awk, split, delimiter, backslash

I'm trying to get the first substring cut along the delimiter of a literal "\n" (actual '\' and 'n' not a new line).

I am able to split the string at the '\' using an octal:

`echo "1234\n5678" | awk -F'\134' '{print $1}'`

But I cannot figure out how to split with the octal as part of a larger string. For example, the following fails:

`echo "1234\n5678" | awk -F'\134'n '{print $1}'`

I can do a string replace on the "\n" with sed and then split on that, but shouldn't I be able to do this simply with awk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you don't have to use `\134`. You can just `-F '\\'`. For your question, you can use

```
    echo "1234\n5678" | awk -F '\\\\n' '{print $1}'
```

`\` is used to escape `\`.

Comment: Strange. I swear I tested that first. I must have had a syntax error somewhere else that was causing it to fail in this case.